# Right join on mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a list of employees,documents and a table that consists of employees and documents,

The document table,

```
docid   mandatory   document
1          1         Birth Certificate
2          0         Drivers License
```

The employee table,

```
empid   empname
1        John
2        Mick
3        Tina
4        Sara
```

The docmentemployee table,

```
empid   docid
1         1
2         1
```

what i would like to get is the list of employees that do not have documents marked as mandatory. My query looks like,

```
select e.empid,e.empname,d.document from `Docemployee` de 
join Docs d on (d.docid=de.docid) 
and mandatory = 1
right join `employee` e on (e.empid=de.empid) ;
```

The result of which is,

```
empid   empname document
1        John   Birth Certificate
2        Mick   Birth Certificate
3        Tina   
4        Sara
```

The desired output is,

```
empid   empname   document
    3     Tina     Birth Certificate
    4     Sara     Birth Certificate
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4c58393f51634789d51c4069150f5fb)

Comment: Nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7766665335011877c5839b051750df44

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c77ef10b50296fcf8aa4c6ba7d61cc6e

Comment: @Akina that looks like the same link i put up

Comment: of course I use your fiddle - but I add a query as 2nd batch.